# Передача коллекции в jsp

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, servlet, hashmap

У меня есть таблицы Book,Genre,genre_to_book(состоит из book_id, genre_id)
Связь между Book и Genre многие ко многим, соответственно genre_to_book - связующая таблица.
Мне нужно на jsp страницу передать коллекцию, которая бы выводила таблицу, отображающую всю информацию о книгах ( в том числе об их жанрах). Я так понимаю, в качестве передаваемого параметра с сервлета в jsp страницу нужно использовать коллекцию, например, такую Map<Book, Genre> map= new HashMap<Book, Genre>();
Правильный ли это подход, и как на самой jsp странице тогда получать данные с такой коллекции, если количество жанров не ограничено для каждой книги
Таблица с jsp страницы ( здесь реализовано для коллекций по типу List)

```
<table class="sort" id="sort">
<tr id="zag">
    <th>Название</th>
    <th>Жанр</th>
    <th>Год выпуска</th>
    <th>Общее количество</th>
    <th>Доступно</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="book" >
    <tr>
        <td>${book.getName() }</td>
        <td>${book.getYear() }</td>
        <td>${book.getCount() }</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Условиt "количество жанров для каждой книги не ограничено" как-то не вяжется с `Map<Book, Genre>`. Может `Map<Book, List<Genre>>`? А вообще список всех элементов map получают так `map.entrySet()`

Comment: Скорее в самой модели в классе `Book` имеет смысл хранить коллекцию/список жанров `class Book {@ManyToMany @JoinTable(name = "genre_to_book", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="book_id"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="genre_id")) List<Genre> genres;}`, тогда на JSP будет передаваться список книг, соответственно у каждой книги будет список её жанров.

Comment: Мне нельзя использовать Hibernate